# How to store the Paypal decimal amount in the MySQLdatabase

Tags: mysql, sql, paypal

Hi in Paypal after transaction the amount should be stored in database.but decimal amount is not storing in the database it convert into whole number.i want to store it in database as decimal number.

for example:amt = 0.5 it storing in MySQL database as 1.i want to store it in database as 0.5

can anyone help me how to do with query.

thanks in advance.

i m new to Paypal and MySQL.if any mistake in my question please fg.

This is my Code

```
       <?php
        define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
          define("DB_USERNAME", "root");
          define("DB_PASSWORD", "");
           define("DB_DATABASE", "test");
          $connect = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD) or die("Database Connection Error");
          mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE) or ("Database Selection Error");

          session_start();
         $uid = $_SESSION['uid'];
          $username=$_SESSION['username'];

          $item_no = isset($_GET['item_number']) ? $_GET['item_number'] : null;
           $item_transaction = isset($_GET['tx']) ? $_GET['tx'] : null ;
                $item_price = isset($_GET['amt']) ? $_GET['amt'] : null ;
             $item_currency = isset($_GET['cc']) ? $_GET['cc'] : null ;;

           $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO sales(pid, uid, saledate,transactionid,amt) VALUES('$item_no', '$uid', NOW(),'$item_transaction','$item_price')");
           if($result){
           echo "<h1>Welcome, $username</h1>";
                echo '<h1>Payment Successful</h1>';

             }else{
                  echo "Payment Error";
                   }


                 ?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your data type of the column must be `decimal` and must have `precision and scale`. The `precision` represents the number of significant digits that are stored for values, and the `scale` represents the number of digits that can be stored following the decimal point.

Example

```
paypalAmount DECIMAL(10,2)
```

by default the value of precision is 10 and the scale is 0. If the value of your scale is `0` then it will not have decimal value and causing to round the value you inserted.

## [*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bd177/1)

Comment: @eggyal exactly, maybe the user did not specify the value for the `scale`.

Comment: Bro can Give me a any links about how to encrypt the buy now button.

Comment: can you please explain more what do you mean by encrypt the button?

Comment: while after transaction it going to success page. the pay pal transaction id showing in the URL i don't want to show the transaction id in the URL